# Naitive :[Err] 1055 - Expression #1

Tags: mysql

After I write on Native:
`"INSERT INTO studentdata(id,name) VALUES(15,'jack');"`,
I can add data, but still report an error:

```
"[Err] 1055 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'information_schema.PROFILING.SEQ' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
"
```

I removed sql_mode=only_full_group_by in my.ini,but still

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: Do you have the SELECT statement you are typing that is throwing the error?  Group and Sort by and Order by all have specific ways and orientation in which they are structured.

Comment: I am running: "SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));"The problem has been solved, but after restarting the software and adding data again, an error will still be reported

Comment: Hmm okay, well that feature is ON by default  unless someone turns it off.  I am reading the error and its saying you have columns that aren't able to be aggregated so I don't think you CAN group them without fixing that table issue.  Are you trying to do this so it will automatically sort the data for you a certain way?  Have you tried manually doing a select statement to build the layout you want to see?

Comment: Ihave tried manually doing the select statement to build the layout to view, is correct and what I was expecting, I was wondering if there is a way to permanently fix this

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and help. I have now found the problem. It is because my software version is too outdated. I am using Navicat11. After I just upgraded navicat16, I connected to the same database and inserted the same data. , navicat16 did not find any problems, I guess it may be because the version is not compatible, navicat16 is more compatible with MySQL8.0 than navicat11